# What is the correct execution command for a crontab job?

Tags: cron

**Set up**

I have several bashfiles on my computer which I want to run periodically.

I can run the bashfiles manually in Terminal (Mac OS), e.g. `cd`'ing myself to the correct folder and subsequently executing,

```
./France_run.txt
```

gives the desired result.

---

**Problem**

I do not want to run the bashfiles manually.

I've created cronjobs in crontab, e.g.

```
 0       0       *       *       2       /Users/mypath/France_run.txt
```

which should run each Tuesday at 00:00. However, nothing happens.

Am I only referring to the file and missing a 'run this script' command? Or is it something else?

Answer (score 0):

You may be only referring to the file, and it's probably logging an error somewhere (usually `/var/log/message`, or in the mail file of the `root` user...which is disabled by default on Macs).

The thing about running scripts through cron is that it runs under a different environment.  When you normally log in to a Bash session, certain environment variables get automatically set, so the system automatically checks for things like a path (locations in the file system where executables can be found).  Different Unix like systems handle this situation slightly differently...I can't recall the details of how Macs deal with it, but on some systems, I've had to explicitly provide the full path to, for example, the Bash executable in order to get stuff to work.

The location of the executable for the scripts is usually `/bin/bash`, or `/bin/sh`, or something like that.  So when going through a Bash session, if you call `/Users/mypath/France_run.txt` and that file is an executable Bash script (e.g. the first line is something like `#!/bin/bash` and the file's executable bit is set) then system knows to automatically run something like `/bin/bash /Users/mypath/France_run.txt`.

In the context of cron, however, you don't automatically get those conveniences, so you may have to spell out just about everything (i.e. specify the full paths to all binaries or executables).  Again, this is not always the case.  I just looked at a Debian system where I created some cron jobs to run scripts, and I didn't have to call `/bin/bash` there, but I do recall having to do something like that int the past on a Mac.

So your cron job may just need to specify the full path to the Bash binary:

`0 0 * * 2 /bin/bash /Users/mypath/France_run.txt`

And if `France_run.txt` makes any calls to system binaries (like `ls`), you may need to fully qualify those as well (`/bin/ls` instead of just `ls`).

Also, depending on how the script is written, it may even be necessary to `cd` into the directory of the script, as if you were running it manually:

`0 0 * * 2 cd /Users/mypath; /bin/bash ./France_run.txt`
(`cd` is a Bash built-in, so there's no path to specify there)